How to lock cells in a formula when a new row is inserted in a table
I am trying to find out the average amount of days it takes to respond within each month. I am using 2 worksheets, worksheet 1 is named 'Apps' and worksheet 2 is named 'Data'.  Below is the table from worksheet 1 with the relevant information:



Column F (Date response submitted)
Column G (Time taken (days)




02/05/2024
0


21/04/2024
-5


13/04/2024
2



Column F has the header 'Date response submitted' and Column G had the header 'Time taken (days). I have named the table 'AppsTable'.
Column F has single dates from January this year and Column G uses another formula to present the response time based on a due date, negative numbers indicate the response was sent before the due date and positive numbers indicate the response was sent after the due date. A zero means column F is empty and so has not been responded to yet.
This is a dynamic table and new rows will be added to the top row regularly with new dates inputted. I am trying to create an equally dynamic formula that updates as new rows are added but I cannot seem to figure out how to lock the cells so the formula incorporates the new 'F2' and 'G2' cells.
The table in worksheet 2 looks like:



Month
Average




Jan
16.23


Feb
1.57



My original code looked like:

=AVERAGE(IF((MONTH(Apps!F2:F246)=1)*(YEAR(Apps!F2:F246)=2024),Apps!G2:G246, "<>0"))

I am aware that the $ locking function does not work for tables so I tried variations of:

=AVERAGE(IF((MONTH(AppTable[@[F2]:[F244]])=5)*(YEAR(AppTable[@[F2]:[F244]])=2024)*(AppTable[@[G2]:[G244]<>0), AppTable[@[G2]:[G244]))

but the 'there is a problem with this formula' pop up keeps appearing. All I am trying to do is lock the F2 and G2 cell so they remain as that, something I thought would be super simple!
There is probably such a simple solution but I do not know enough about excel functions to figure it out so TIA

It sounds like you're trying to refer to a column in such a way that your formula will be able to handle new rows being added into the table. In that case, you can use structured references such as AppTable[Date response submitted] to refer to a column and AppTable[@[Date response submitted]] within a row to refer to the value in that column for that row. Does that help, or have I misunderstood the requirement?

Hi thanks for you response! You have understood correctly I do believe, I can reference the whole column. I have tried: '=AVERAGE(IF((MONTH(AppTable[Date response submitted])=1)*(YEAR(AppTable[Date response submitted])=2024),AppTable[Time taken (days)], "<>0"))' Have I wrapped it correctly? Because I am still getting the error pop up box.

Have a look at the AVERAGEIFS() function. I believe the problematic part of your formula is "<>0", in which you're passing the literal string value "<>0" as an argument to the AVERAGE() function which expects a number.

So if I understand correctly, you're inserting rows on the top, thus moving your data down?
One way to make sure your formulas are referencing to the right cell, if that cell always stays on the same position, is using INDIRECT.
In your case, whenever you reference to G2, try using INDIRECT("G2") instead.
Or, if you want it somewhat more dynamic/eassier to change, use a helper cell, say AA1 and use INDIRECT(AA1) and type G2  in cell AA1; however, you have to make sure that cell AA1 always remains on that position.

Thank you! Yes you understand correctly. I have seen INDIRECT mentioned before but I'm not sure how to wrap it. I have just tried =AVERAGE(IF((MONTH(INDIRECT("Apps!F2")=1)*(YEAR(INDIRECT("Apps!F2")=2024), INDIRECT("Apps!G2"), "<>0")) which is not working either.

What error are you getting when you say it's not working? the 'formula error' you mentioned in your post? Also, unsure what you're trying to achieve with the "<>0" at the end?
